# как найти в Ubuntu где лежит папка с программой?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

Вот простой пример. Я скачал chrome и теперь не знаю как его запустить через терминал. Насколько я знаю, нужно найти

```
chrome --> bin --> fail.sh
```

Но как найти где папка chrome?
Перепыл всю систему не пойму. В windows просто нажал правой кнопкой и свойства и там путь...
Что я не так делаю?

Comment: что значит «скачал chrome»?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вообще, запускаемый файл браузера Chrome называется `google-chrome` или `google-chrome-stable`. Найти полный путь к запускаемому файлу можно командой:

```
which <имя файла>
which google-chrome-stable
```

При условии, что файл находится в одной из папок, перечисленных в переменной окружения `$PATH`. Если это не так, найти его можно командой

```
find / -name <имя файла>
```

Но тогда и запустить его из консоли можно будет только как

```
/full/path/to/<имя файла>
```

Последняя команда найдет файл по имени, даже если он не запускаемый, если хватит прав.

Comment: Просто добавлю: можно ещё и с помощью locate <имя файла>

Comment: Спасибо ответившим! Помогло разобраться)

Answer (score 2):

Чаще всего хватает

```
whereis файл
```

Но если не находит, то можно поискать обычным способом

```
find / -name chrome
```

На моей убунте он установлен в /opt/google/chrome

Comment: да действительно. У меня там же сохранен... Но я почему то не могу найти file.sh для запуска приложения... Как я могу его запустить тогда?

Comment: просто выполняешь /opt/google/chrome/chrome